# ee.Image.sample not working with MODIS NDVI ("MODIS/MOD09GA_006_NDVI") dataset in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

The code snippet shared below does not yield any feature in the feature collection (**vectors**), the below code works well with Sentinel-2 (**COPERNICUS/S2_SR**) dataset on earth engine.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09GA_006_NDVI')
                  .filterBounds(AOI)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-04-01', '2019-06-01'));

print(dataset);
var image = (dataset.select('NDVI')).toBands();
print(image);

var vectors = image.sample({
  region: AOI,
  geometries: true  // if you want points
});

print(vectors);

Map.centerObject(AOI);
Map.addLayer(image.clip(AOI));
Map.addLayer(vectors);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2de51edb8909037fa884e099f68897e2

would like to understand the underlying limitation(s) of the dataset used or of the google earth engine system (if any) while using the data in question.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `sample()`:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-sample

> Note that the default behavior is to drop features that intersect
> masked pixels, which result in null-valued properties (see dropNulls
> argument).